# EF6 Code First: How can I centralize content for separate sections of my site?

Tags: entity-framework-6.1

I want to store all our site's content in one central Content table but relate it to each section of the site. Something like:

- Content (for the actual content byte[] and basic info all sections use)
- ResearchArticleContent (basically has the related ContentId from the content table and extra cols for info specific to ResearchArticles)
- ResearchArticle
- ExecutiveContent (basically has the related ContentID from Content table and extra cols for specific data for Executives)
- Executive

...and so on.
I'm having trouble understanding the whole code first approach as it pertains to ForeignKeys and InverseProperties. That's the real issue.

So, say I have these two classes as an example:

```
 public class Content
{
    [Key]
    public int ContentId { get; set; }
    public int ContentType { get; set; }         
    public byte[] ContentBytes { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }

    [**`InverseProperty or ForeignKey???`**("ResearchArticleContent")]
    public virtual ResearchArticleContent ResearchArticleContent { get; set; }        
}
```

and:

```
 public class ResearchArticleContent
{
    [Key]
    public int ResearchArticleContentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ContentId")]
    public virtual Content Content {get;set;}

    public int ResearchArticleId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ResearchArticleId")]
    public virtual ResearchArticle RelatedArticle { get; set; }
}
```

Where do I put the ForeignKeys / InverseProperties to relate these correctly. Because ideally, I will have Executivecontent, ResearchArticlecontent and so on for each section of the site. (I am following the precedent already laid out in a Data-First prj that I am mimicking so this is the way I have do this, fyi.)

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework requires a type identifier field when you store compound objects in a single table; however, you can get around this pretty easily using views. To use views, create a single content table and a > base < class. Do not apply the TableAttribute data annotation to the base class. All other data annotations are fine.

```
public class ContentBase
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ContentId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then, you can create derived classes that more closely represent the content and apply the TableAttribute data annotation to those. For example,

```
[Table("ResearchArticleView")]
public class ResearchArticle : ContentBase
{
   ...you can add more properties here that are included in the view...
   ...and not necessarily the underlying table, like from a joined table...
   ...or just use the class as is, so that you have a better name...
}
```

To use this, set up a view called ResearchArticleView that includes the columns in the base class, as well as any computed or joined columns you want, then add a DbSet to your context that represents the view.

I recommend having content tables for each type of content and then use the method I've described for derived types for each content type. For example, create a base for research articles and a base for execute content. Because, when your database gets big and full of content, having one monolithic content table may cause you backup and optimization issues.

Comment: I have a working example of this on www.crowdit.com. I created a DreamBase class that contains all of the base properties. Then, I created a Dream class to represent the actual Dreams table. Finally, I created a DreamView object that derives from DreamBase and implements some aggregate properties. DreamView represents a view that I created from the Dreams table and it contains some aggregated data. This is very similar to what you're trying to accomplish, I think.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your way makes sense and is what I initially was doing. however, I was told to do it the 'monolithic way' as you describe, so this answer doesn't help me. Thanks though. I still need my original question answered as it stands.

Comment: Oh, I gotcha...I didn't quite understand your question I guess. So, all you're really wanting is to set up navigation properties? If that's the case, do you really need to navigate from the Content object to the object that references it?  (You can have navigation properties that only go one direction.)

Comment: I see your point. I am ultra new at EF/Code First so, the terms are all new, the relationships between them, all new, so I need to see code, not English because the terms mean nothing to me until I code with them. Just the way I work, lol

Comment: FYI, I got one-to-many working between ResearchArticle and ResearchArticleContent. But they are one-many. Many content per article. Now I'm working on  Executive/ExecutiveContent/Content which is 1:1:1, and I cannot figure it out. Should I post a fresh question at this point?

Comment: I'm not a moderator. It's probably ok to update your original question and show your class definitions for ResearchArticle and ResearchArticleContent. Does ResearchArticleContent have a collection of Content objects?

Comment: Here is a more specific question about your data structure. Are you wanting a one-to-many relationship between ResearchArticle and ResearchArticleContent, with no relationship to Content?. And also one-to-one relationship between Executive and ExecutiveContent and then another one-to-one relationship between ExecutiveContent and Content?  Or, do you have (or are wanting) both ExecutiveContent and ResearchArticleContent to have a relationship to the Content table?